# Installing Dokku on ubuntu throws error

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I'm having a lot of trouble installing Dokku on an Ubuntu server. I feel like I've tried almost everything. I'm on Ubuntu 18.04.2, and I'm trying to install the latest Dokku version (0.15.5).
Here is the TRACE log while trying to install the software. Dpkg keeps throwing an error, and I'm not sure how to check what error it is.

Here is the log:

```
root@viggo-server:/# TRACE=1 apt-get install -f --reinstall dokku
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  dokku
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
23 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/38.7 MB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Preconfiguring packages ...
+ [[ -e /usr/share/debconf/confmodule ]]
+ . /usr/share/debconf/confmodule
++ '[' '!' 1 ']'
++ '[' -z '' ']'
++ exec
++ '[' '' ']'
++ exec
++ DEBCONF_REDIR=1
++ export DEBCONF_REDIR
+ readonly ACTION=configure
+ ACTION=configure
+ readonly VERSION=dev
+ VERSION=dev
+ db_input high dokku/web_config
+ _db_cmd 'INPUT high' dokku/web_config
+ _db_internal_IFS='
'
+ IFS=' '
+ printf '%s\n' 'INPUT high dokku/web_config'
+ IFS='
'
+ IFS='
'
+ read -r _db_internal_line
+ RET='30 question skipped'
+ case ${_db_internal_line%%[   ]*} in
+ return 30
+ true
+ db_go
+ _db_cmd 'GO '
+ _db_internal_IFS='
'
+ IFS=' '
+ printf '%s\n' 'GO '
+ IFS='
'
+ IFS='
'
+ read -r _db_internal_line
+ RET=ok
+ case ${_db_internal_line%%[   ]*} in
+ return 0
+ db_get dokku/web_config
+ _db_cmd 'GET dokku/web_config'
+ _db_internal_IFS='
'
+ IFS=' '
+ printf '%s\n' 'GET dokku/web_config'
+ IFS='
'
+ IFS='
'
+ read -r _db_internal_line
+ RET=false
+ case ${_db_internal_line%%[   ]*} in
+ return 0
+ '[' false = true ']'
+ db_input high dokku/nginx_enable
+ _db_cmd 'INPUT high' dokku/nginx_enable
+ _db_internal_IFS='
'
+ IFS=' '
+ printf '%s\n' 'INPUT high dokku/nginx_enable'
+ IFS='
'
+ IFS='
'
+ read -r _db_internal_line
+ RET='30 question skipped'
+ case ${_db_internal_line%%[   ]*} in
+ return 30
+ true
+ db_input high dokku/hostname
+ _db_cmd 'INPUT high' dokku/hostname
+ _db_internal_IFS='
'
+ IFS=' '
+ printf '%s\n' 'INPUT high dokku/hostname'
+ IFS='
'
+ IFS='
'
+ read -r _db_internal_line
+ RET='30 question skipped'
+ case ${_db_internal_line%%[   ]*} in
+ return 30
+ true
+ db_input high dokku/vhost_enable
+ _db_cmd 'INPUT high' dokku/vhost_enable
+ _db_internal_IFS='
'
+ IFS=' '
+ printf '%s\n' 'INPUT high dokku/vhost_enable'
+ IFS='
'
+ IFS='
'
+ read -r _db_internal_line
+ RET='30 question skipped'
+ case ${_db_internal_line%%[   ]*} in
+ return 30
+ true
+ '[' configure '!=' reconfigure ']'
+ db_input high dokku/key_file
+ _db_cmd 'INPUT high' dokku/key_file
+ _db_internal_IFS='
'
+ IFS=' '
+ printf '%s\n' 'INPUT high dokku/key_file'
+ IFS='
'
+ IFS='
'
+ read -r _db_internal_line
+ RET='question will be asked'
+ case ${_db_internal_line%%[   ]*} in
+ return 0
+ db_go
+ _db_cmd 'GO '
+ _db_internal_IFS='
'
+ IFS=' '
+ printf '%s\n' 'GO '
+ IFS='
'
+ IFS='
'
+ read -r _db_internal_line
+ RET=ok
+ case ${_db_internal_line%%[   ]*} in
+ return 0
(Reading database ... 120732 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../dokku_0.15.5_amd64.deb ...
+ [[ -e /usr/share/debconf/confmodule ]]
+ . /usr/share/debconf/confmodule
++ '[' '!' '' ']'
++ PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1
++ export PERL_DL_NONLAZY
++ '[' '' ']'
++ exec /usr/share/debconf/frontend /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/preinst install
+ [[ -e /usr/share/debconf/confmodule ]]
+ . /usr/share/debconf/confmodule
++ '[' '!' 1 ']'
++ '[' -z '' ']'
++ exec
++ '[' '' ']'
++ exec
++ DEBCONF_REDIR=1
++ export DEBCONF_REDIR
+ readonly ACTION=configure
+ ACTION=configure
+ readonly VERSION=dev
+ VERSION=dev
+ db_input high dokku/web_config
+ _db_cmd 'INPUT high' dokku/web_config
+ _db_internal_IFS='
'
+ IFS=' '
+ printf '%s\n' 'INPUT high dokku/web_config'
+ IFS='
'
+ IFS='
'
+ read -r _db_internal_line
+ RET='30 question skipped'
+ case ${_db_internal_line%%[   ]*} in
+ return 30
+ true
+ db_go
+ _db_cmd 'GO '
+ _db_internal_IFS='
'
+ IFS=' '
+ printf '%s\n' 'GO '
+ IFS='
'
+ IFS='
'
+ read -r _db_internal_line
+ RET=ok
+ case ${_db_internal_line%%[   ]*} in
+ return 0
+ db_get dokku/web_config
+ _db_cmd 'GET dokku/web_config'
+ _db_internal_IFS='
'
+ IFS=' '
+ printf '%s\n' 'GET dokku/web_config'
+ IFS='
'
+ IFS='
'
+ read -r _db_internal_line
+ RET=false
+ case ${_db_internal_line%%[   ]*} in
+ return 0
+ '[' false = true ']'
+ db_input high dokku/nginx_enable
+ _db_cmd 'INPUT high' dokku/nginx_enable
+ _db_internal_IFS='
'
+ IFS=' '
+ printf '%s\n' 'INPUT high dokku/nginx_enable'
+ IFS='
'
+ IFS='
'
+ read -r _db_internal_line
+ RET='30 question skipped'
+ case ${_db_internal_line%%[   ]*} in
+ return 30
+ true
+ db_input high dokku/hostname
+ _db_cmd 'INPUT high' dokku/hostname
+ _db_internal_IFS='
'
+ IFS=' '
+ printf '%s\n' 'INPUT high dokku/hostname'
+ IFS='
'
+ IFS='
'
+ read -r _db_internal_line
+ RET='30 question skipped'
+ case ${_db_internal_line%%[   ]*} in
+ return 30
+ true
+ db_input high dokku/vhost_enable
+ _db_cmd 'INPUT high' dokku/vhost_enable
+ _db_internal_IFS='
'
+ IFS=' '
+ printf '%s\n' 'INPUT high dokku/vhost_enable'
+ IFS='
'
+ IFS='
'
+ read -r _db_internal_line
+ RET='30 question skipped'
+ case ${_db_internal_line%%[   ]*} in
+ return 30
+ true
+ '[' configure '!=' reconfigure ']'
+ db_input high dokku/key_file
+ _db_cmd 'INPUT high' dokku/key_file
+ _db_internal_IFS='
'
+ IFS=' '
+ printf '%s\n' 'INPUT high dokku/key_file'
+ IFS='
'
+ IFS='
'
+ read -r _db_internal_line
+ RET='30 question skipped'
+ case ${_db_internal_line%%[   ]*} in
+ return 30
+ true
+ db_go
+ _db_cmd 'GO '
+ _db_internal_IFS='
'
+ IFS=' '
+ printf '%s\n' 'GO '
+ IFS='
'
+ IFS='
'
+ read -r _db_internal_line
+ RET=ok
+ case ${_db_internal_line%%[   ]*} in
+ return 0
+ [[ -e /usr/share/debconf/confmodule ]]
+ . /usr/share/debconf/confmodule
++ '[' '!' 1 ']'
++ '[' -z '' ']'
++ exec
++ '[' '' ']'
++ exec
++ DEBCONF_REDIR=1
++ export DEBCONF_REDIR
+ case "$1" in
+ db_get dokku/web_config
+ _db_cmd 'GET dokku/web_config'
+ _db_internal_IFS='
'
+ IFS=' '
+ printf '%s\n' 'GET dokku/web_config'
+ IFS='
'
+ IFS='
'
+ read -r _db_internal_line
+ RET=false
+ case ${_db_internal_line%%[   ]*} in
+ return 0
+ '[' false = true ']'
+ db_get dokku/skip_key_file
+ _db_cmd 'GET dokku/skip_key_file'
+ _db_internal_IFS='
'
+ IFS=' '
+ printf '%s\n' 'GET dokku/skip_key_file'
+ IFS='
'
+ IFS='
'
+ read -r _db_internal_line
+ RET=false
+ case ${_db_internal_line%%[   ]*} in
+ return 0
+ '[' -z '' ']'
+ '[' false '!=' true ']'
+ db_get dokku/key_file
+ _db_cmd 'GET dokku/key_file'
+ _db_internal_IFS='
'
+ IFS=' '
+ printf '%s\n' 'GET dokku/key_file'
+ IFS='
'
+ IFS='
'
+ read -r _db_internal_line
+ RET=/root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
+ case ${_db_internal_line%%[   ]*} in
+ return 0
+ '[' '!' -f /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub ']'
+ echo 'Error: keyfile '\''/root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub'\'' not found.'
Error: keyfile '/root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub' not found.
+ echo '       you can enter a new keyfile path when you restart the installation.'
       you can enter a new keyfile path when you restart the installation.
+ db_reset dokku/key_file
+ _db_cmd 'RESET dokku/key_file'
+ _db_internal_IFS='
'
+ IFS=' '
+ printf '%s\n' 'RESET dokku/key_file'
+ IFS='
'
+ IFS='
'
+ read -r _db_internal_line
+ RET=0
+ case ${_db_internal_line%%[   ]*} in
+ return 0
+ exit 1
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/dokku_0.15.5_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 new dokku package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
+ [[ -e /usr/share/debconf/confmodule ]]
+ . /usr/share/debconf/confmodule
++ '[' '!' '' ']'
++ PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1
++ export PERL_DL_NONLAZY
++ '[' '' ']'
++ exec /usr/share/debconf/frontend /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/postrm abort-install
+ [[ -e /usr/share/debconf/confmodule ]]
+ . /usr/share/debconf/confmodule
++ '[' '!' 1 ']'
++ '[' -z '' ']'
++ exec
++ '[' '' ']'
++ exec
++ DEBCONF_REDIR=1
++ export DEBCONF_REDIR
+ readonly DOKKU_ROOT=/home/dokku
+ DOKKU_ROOT=/home/dokku
+ readonly DOKKU_LIB_ROOT=/var/lib/dokku
+ DOKKU_LIB_ROOT=/var/lib/dokku
+ readonly DOKKU_LOGS_DIR=/var/log/dokku
+ DOKKU_LOGS_DIR=/var/log/dokku
+ main abort-install
+ [[ -f /etc/systemd/system/dokku-installer.service ]]
+ [[ -f /etc/init/dokku-installer.conf ]]
+ rm -f /etc/init/dokku-installer.conf
+ rm -f /etc/init/dokku-redeploy.conf
+ rm -f /etc/systemd/system/dokku-installer.service
+ rm -f /etc/systemd/system/dokku-redeploy.service
+ rm -f /etc/update-motd.d/99-dokku
+ db_get dokku/nginx_enable
+ _db_cmd 'GET dokku/nginx_enable'
+ _db_internal_IFS='
'
+ IFS=' '
+ printf '%s\n' 'GET dokku/nginx_enable'
+ IFS='
'
+ IFS='
'
+ read -r _db_internal_line
+ RET=true
+ case ${_db_internal_line%%[   ]*} in
+ return 0
+ '[' true = true ']'
+ nginx -t
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
+ service nginx reload
nginx.service is not active, cannot reload.
+ true
+ [[ abort-install == \p\u\r\g\e ]]
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/dokku_0.15.5_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I hope you can help me, I'm so stuck. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately none of these solutions worked. I did however end up solving it, by clearing my apt preferences, as suggested here: https://github.com/dokku/dokku/issues/1710

So in a way you helped me, thank you Jose.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though you somehow disabled Nginx. You'll need to enable it for the installation to continue properly. I believe the correct command is:

```
service nginx enable
```

Comment: That is not what `nginx.service is not active, cannot reload` means. It means the service is not currently running, not that the service is disabled.

Comment: Ah sorry, then I guess starting the service should have helped :)

Answer (score 0):

If you search for the word "Error" in the output you pasted, you will see the following lines:

```
+ echo 'Error: keyfile '\''/root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub'\'' not found.'
Error: keyfile '/root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub' not found.
+ echo '       you can enter a new keyfile path when you restart the installation.'
       you can enter a new keyfile path when you restart the installation.
```

If you look at the Dokku [Debian/Ubuntu Installation Instructions](https://github.com/dokku/dokku/blob/master/docs/getting-started/install/debian.md), you will see that it requires the presence of an SSH key belonging to the `root` user. You don't have one.

Run `ssh-keygen` as the root user to generate an SSH keypair, and then try to install again. Alternatively, if you have an existing SSH key you would like to use, follow the instructions linked above.